# How to send a dictionary over a rpc

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine, rpc

So I'm making a multiplayer game in unity.
Ive built some Dictionary's to hold scores.
The master client handles the Dictionary's.

After the master client makes a change to the dictionary's (because a player died for example)and calculated who is in the lead. I want to send the data to the clients so they can update there scoreboards, hud, ect.

However I cant seem to dictionary directly through a rpc. for example here

```
[RPC]
void PassScoresToClients (Dictionary plyScrs, Dictionary teamScrs,int leadingTeamID, int leadingTeamScore){

}
```

The word Dictionary just turns red.

Is there a way I can send this data over to the clients?

For the sake of argument I'm going to give a brief example of it.
The First dictionary Holds the player's Kills, Deaths, Assists And teamID using there Username As the dictionary Key. and score type (Kills, Deaths, Assists And teamID) as the secondary key.
its structured like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int> > playerScores;
```

The sub Dictionary gets created/populated when needed to like this

```
public void SetScore (string username, string scoreType, int value)
{
        Init ();
        changeCounter ++;

        if (playerScores.ContainsKey (username) == false) {//if the player has not been recorded in the dictionery yet.
                    playerScores [username] = new Dictionary<string, int> ();// Creates a new dictinerey(sub dictionery) for that player.
        }

        playerScores [username] [scoreType] = value; // the players score is now the value of value
}
```

The 2nd Dictionary is a simple one that just keeps track of the teams scores.
it uses the the teamID's as key
its structured like this:

```
Dictionary<int, int> teamScores;
```

The Dictionary's are populated by the master client so the clients only have complementary empty Dictionary's in till they can receive the data.

so is there a way to send the data over to the clients?

oh and if you do post code could you please put in comments. Im still pretty noobish at a lot of things and get lost very easy.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the generic dictionary on you RPC:

```
[RPC]
void PassScoresToClients (Dictionary<int, int> plyScrs, Dictionary<int, int> teamScrs, int leadingTeamID, int leadingTeamScore){

}
```

`Dictionary` and `Dictionay<int, int>` are not automatically convertible among themselves.